# SecureSAXParserFactory error in the gdata calendar sample code

Tags: android, calendar, gdata-api

i am currently using gdata vesion 1.41.3 and android api level 3.
i am trying to use the Calendar feature of gdata. my source code is]

```
try {

   CalendarService myService = new CalendarService(
     "exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
   myService.setUserCredentials("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");

   // Send the request and print the response
   URL feedUrl = new URL(
     "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full");
   CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl,
     CalendarFeed.class);
   System.out.println("Your calendars:");
   System.out.println();
   for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
    CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
    System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("", e.toString());
  }
```

the code throwing following Exception:

```
com.google.gdata.util.common.xml.parsing.SecureGenericXMLFactory$SecureSAXParserFactory
```

need help ???

Comment: That is a class. It is not an exception. What is the exception and stack trace?

Comment: sorry, below is the exception:

java.lang.VerifyError: com.google.gdata.util.common.xml.parsing.SecureGenericXMLFactory$SecureSAXParserFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

till now gdata not supported on android.
http://code.google.com/p/android-gdata/

no g data libraries available.

Answer (score 0):

you can you use GoogleApiJavaClient
see here why :
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient

look here for more resource
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/